# Typescript export keyword

Tags: javascript, typescript

Quick question about Typescript and export keyword.
I currently correctly understanding the usage of export, import etc...

But when I compile my TS file into JS, the word export is present ( I use ES5 ) and it throw an error.

For example :

```
export class A{
}
```

generate :

```
"use strict";
var A = (function () {
    return A;
}());

exports.A = A;
```

My code works but throw

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

if I delete the export keyword, the same file is generated without `exports.A = A`

But when I tried to use it into my unit test it throw :

> TypeError: A is not a constructor

If someone can highlight me in this point...

EDIT :

Here my tsconfig :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
        //"outFile": "js/powerfull-rating.js",
    },

    "include": [
        "src/ts/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please share your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Based on the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" it looks like your typed `exports` instead of `export`. It should be `export` **without** and "s" letter/character.

Comment: No i'm using correctly the word export ^^.  The word exports is the one generated in the JS file

Comment: What environment are you running your code in? Look at the [module compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: i'm running the code in macOs Sierra with visual studio. I use gulp task to executer typescript compilation. I will look the options, thanks for the link

Comment: When exactly are you getting the ReferenceError? It sounds like you're trying to run the compiled code somewhere that doesn't support modules (like a browser).

Comment: I get the error when i run the compiled JavaScript in Chrome. My code is working i just not understand why he use Export keyword while I'm targeting ES5

Comment: That'd do it. :) You need a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), browsers don't understand modules. Browserify and the [Tsify](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify) plugin would probably be the simpler way to get started, Webpack can be tricky.

Comment: I am currently using gulp-typescript... so it can comes from this. Is not a big deal because the code is running, thanks for your answer guys :)